# Under what condition can we analytically continue an equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have an equation
$$(\partial_x^2+b\partial_x+h(x))f(x)=g(x)$$
which we known is satisfied for real $x$.

Under what conditions, can we continue it to
$$(\partial_z^2+b\partial_z+h(z))f(z)=g(z)$$
for complex $z$?